# Подавить вывод при запуске нескольких скриптов

Tags: powershell

Товарищи, добрый день!
Потратил около 3-х часов на попытки найти решение в гугл, но всё безрезультатно.
Есть набор скриптов, должны быть автоматически запущены при logon пользователя на ПК, так же они должны быть доступны для ручного запуска.
Для назначения в GPO создан один скрипт, который управляет условиями и очередностью выполнения скриптов.
Проблема - в каждом скрипте есть `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$errMSG", "Ошибка", "OK", "Error")` и для отображения ошибок, и для успешного выполнения при ручном запуске. Скрипты вызываются через Start-Job внутри if при выполнении некоторых условий

```
if ($PC -eq 1){
    Start-Job -Name 'ScriptJob1' { Set-Location C:\123} -FilePath .\Script1.ps1"
    Wait-Job -Name 'ScriptJob1'
}
```

Пробовал `--quiet --no-verbose >$null 2>&1` в разных вариациях, окна `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]` всё равно отображаются по окончании выполнения скрипта.
Подскажите, существует ли способ полностью подавить вывод результата скрипта при его вызове из другого скрипта? Так же пытался использовать `Receive-Job | out-null` и подобные конструкции для перенаправления - но безуспешно.

Comment: Перенаправление (>) используется для консольного вывода. В Ваших скриптах же специально используются WinForms для сообщений. Отсюда вижу 3 варианта: **1.** Переписать код скриптов. **2.** Пересобирать код в новые скрипты,копируя исходные, с выключением функции (MessageBox, etc.). **3.** Отслеживать появление окон сообщений и закрывать их, либо запускать скрипты как задания Планировщика в виде скрытой задачи. Объективно нужно работать по **1-му варианту**, остальное - это мартышкин труд. Судя по контексту вопроса Вы не являетесь администратором систем, раз не можете модифицировать код скриптов.

Comment: Я могу переписать код скриптов, вопрос в другом. Если убрать из кода MessageBox, как ещё можно регулировать вывод при ручном запуске?
Т.е. как можно заставить один и тот же скрипт при ручном запуске показывать окно, при автоматическом через GPO - нет. Предполагал, что это возможно сделать единым скриптом-оркестратором, отсюда и такой вопрос.

Comment: При запуске скриптов в ручном режиме добавьте любой определенный параметр командной строки. Если он существует, значит скрипт запущен вручную. Либо отслеживайте по местоположению запускаемого скрипта, например, по значению  `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition`

Comment: @Daemon-5 
Действительно, добавил в начало каждого скрипта параметр с указанием дефолтного значения, при вызове из оркестратора просто его заменяю. И где моя логика была раньше... 
Спасибо!